# Affine Kac-Moody algebra from quantum group exchange algebra

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-field-theory, string-theory, kac-moody-algebras

In [`Hidden Quantum Groups Inside Kac-Moody Algebra'](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1104251225), by Alekseev, Faddeev, and Semenov-Tian-Shansky, a relationship between **quantum groups** and **affine Kac-Moody algebras** is shown for the WZW model.

Towards this end, the authors show that a certain **exchange algebra** (that is implied by the quantum group relations) implies the **algebra between a current and local operator** given in equation (45), i.e.,
$$[J_1(x), u_2(y)] = 2~\textrm{ln}(q)Pu_2(y)δ(x-y), $$
where the subscripts '1' and '2' indicate the relevant tensor factor the operators are valued in.
They claim this is a straightforward computation, but I cannot arrive at their result precisely, and am wondering if they have made an error.

My derivation is as follows.

1. They start from the exchange algebra (equation (33))
   $$
   u_1(x)u_2(y)=u_2(y)u_1(x)R(x-y),
   $$
   where $R(x-y)$ is given in (42) as
   $$
   R(x-y)=F_{12}q^{Psign(x-y)}F^{-1}_{21},
   $$
   and essentially encodes two **R-matrices** that satisfy the quantum group relations. Here $P$ is the **permutation operator**, $F_{12}$ is an invertible matrix in $\mathbb{C}\otimes \mathbb{C}$, and $F_{21}=PF_{12}P$.
2. Playing around with the algebra (33), it is easy to arrive at (44), which is equivalent to
   \begin{equation}\tag{1}
   u'_1(x+\epsilon)u_1(x)^{-1}u_2(y+\epsilon)=u'_1(x+\epsilon)u_2(y+\epsilon)R(x-y-\epsilon)^{-1}u_1(x)^{-1}.
   \end{equation}
   I am also able to derive the expansion of $R(x-y-\epsilon)^{-1}$, i.e.,
   $$R(x-y-\epsilon)^{-1}=R(x-y)^{-1}+2 \epsilon \textrm{ ln}(q) F_{21}P F_{12}^{-1}\delta(x-y)+O(\epsilon^2),$$
   where I have used $
   R(x-y)^{-1}=F_{21}q^{-Psign(x-y)}F^{-1}_{12}
   $, $sign (0)=0$ and $\frac{d}{dx}sign(x)=2\delta(x)$. This is equivalent to the expression below (44) since $F_{21}P F_{12}^{-1}=P=F_{12}P F_{21}^{-1}$.
3. Next I expand (1) in $\epsilon$, using equation (36), which is equivalent to
   $$
   u'_1(x+\epsilon)u_1(x)^{-1}=A_1+\epsilon J_1(x) + O(\epsilon^2)
   $$
   (where $A=a I_1$ for some constant $a$, and $J(x)$ is the WZW current), and
   $$
   u_2(y+\epsilon)=u_2(y)+\epsilon u'_2(y)+O(\epsilon^2).
   $$
   I also use
   $$
   u_2(y+\epsilon)u'_1(x+\epsilon)=u'_1(x+\epsilon)u_2(y+\epsilon)R(x-y)^{-1}+u_1(x+\epsilon)u_2(y+\epsilon)
   \frac{d}{dx}R(x-y)^{-1},$$
   (where $\frac{d}{dx}R(x-y)^{-1}=-2\textrm{ln}(q)P\delta(x-y)$) which follows from the exchange algebra relation.
4. Doing so, I arrive at
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   A_1 u_2(y)+\epsilon J_1(x)u_2(y) +\epsilon A_1 u'_2(y)=&u_2(y)A_1+\epsilon u_2'(y)A_1 + \epsilon u_2(y)J_1(x)  \\ & +2\epsilon \textrm{ln}(q) Pu_2(y)\delta(x-y) \\& + 2\epsilon \textrm{ln}(q) Pu_2(y) A_1 \delta(x-y) + O(\epsilon^2),
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   (assuming that $u_1(x+\epsilon)u_1(x)^{-1}=\epsilon I_1 + O(\epsilon^2)$, which is not provided, but seems natural and brings me closest to their answer)
   which implies (by collecting order $\epsilon$ terms) that
   $$
   [J_1(x), u_2(y)] = 2(1+a)~\textrm{ln}(q)Pu_2(y)δ(x-y).
   $$
   This is different from equation (45), as there is a factor of $(1+a)$ on the RHS.

Have I made a mistake, or is there an error in the paper?

**Note**: Based on მამუკა ჯიბლაძე's comments, I tried using $u'_1(x+\epsilon)u_1(x)^{-1}=\frac{A_1}{\epsilon}+J_1(x) + O(\epsilon)$ and $u_1(x+\epsilon)u_1(x)^{-1}=I_1 + O(\epsilon)$, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Cross-post at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/584708/wzw-model-affine-kac-moody-current-algebra-from-quantum-group-exchange-algebra

Comment: Re "slightly different" [from the expression below (44)]: it is the same. Since $F_{21}=PF_{12}P$, both $F_{12}PF_{21}^{-1}$ and $F_{21}PF_{12}^{-1}$ are equal to just $P$.

Comment: მამუკა ჯიბლაძე Thanks, I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your expression for $u_1(x+\epsilon)u_1(x)^{-1}$. It implies that this quantity is $\epsilon$-close to zero, while actually it must be $\epsilon$-close to the identity. I believe it should be $I_1+O(\epsilon)$, no?

Comment: I thought so too, but when I look at equation (36), it should go to $u’(x)u(x)^{-1}=J(x)$ as $\epsilon$ goes to zero, but this is not the case either. I am rather confused about this.

Comment: I think your observation is important, it seems that (36) has a typo on the LHS, there should be no 1/epsilon

Comment: Maybe: it must be consistent with (37), which it seems not to be as written. Also, they say that $u'(x)u(x)^{-1}=J(x)$ is not quite true because of possible singularities.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that even when I use $u'_1(x+\epsilon)u_1(x)^{-1}=\frac{A_1}{\epsilon}+J_1(x) + O(\epsilon)$ and $u_1(x+\epsilon)u_1(x)^{-1}=I_1 + O(\epsilon)$, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1):

$\let\eps\varepsilon$

I believe there is an error in the expression for the derivative of $R^{-1}$, it should be
$$
\frac{d}{dx}R(x-y)^{-1}=-2\textrm{ln}(q)P\delta(x-y)R(x-y)^{-1}
$$

Accordingly, one must have
$$
R(x-y-\epsilon)^{-1}=(1+2\eps\ln(q)\delta(x-y)P)R(x-y)^{-1}+O(\epsilon^2).
$$
Substituting this into your
$$
u'_1(x+\eps)u_1(x)^{-1}u_2(y+\eps)=u'_1(x+\eps)u_2(y+\eps)R(x-y-\eps)^{-1}u_1(x)^{-1}.
$$
gives
\begin{align*}
u'_1(x+\eps)u_1(x)^{-1}u_2(y+\eps)=&
u'_1(x+\eps)u_2(y+\eps)R(x-y)^{-1}u_1(x)^{-1}\\
+&2\eps\ln(q)\delta(x-y)u'_1(x+\eps)u_2(y+\eps)PR(x-y)^{-1}u_1(x)^{-1}
\end{align*}

Also your expression at the end of 3. should be
\begin{multline*}
u'_1(x+\eps)u_2(y+\eps)R(x-y)^{-1}\\
=u_2(y+\eps)u'_1(x+\eps)+2\ln(q)\delta(x-y)Pu_1(x+\eps)u_2(y+\eps)R(x-y)^{-1}.
\end{multline*}
Substituting it gives
\begin{align*}
u'_1(x+\eps)u_1(x)^{-1}u_2(y+\eps&)=
u_2(y+\eps)u'_1(x+\eps)u_1(x)^{-1}\\
&+2\ln(q)\delta(x-y)Pu_1(x+\eps)u_2(y+\eps)R(x-y)^{-1}u_1(x)^{-1}\\
&+2\eps\ln(q)\delta(x-y)u'_1(x+\eps)u_2(y+\eps)PR(x-y)^{-1}u_1(x)^{-1}.
\end{align*}
Then, presuming the correct version of (36) is
$$
u'(x+\eps)u(x)^{-1}=\frac1\eps A+J(x)+O(\eps),
$$
we get
$$
[J_1(x),u_2(y)]=2\ln(q)\delta(x-y)Pu_1(x)u_2(y)R(x-y)^{-1}u_1(x)^{-1}+O(\eps),
$$
which gives the needed equality.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is a very nice proof. I am a little confused by the first line though, when I take the derivative of $R(x-y)^{-1}$, I get $F_{21} (- 2\textrm{ln}(q) P \delta(x-y)) q^{-Psign(x-y)}F^{-1}_{12}$. I can't seem to change this into the form you get, unless $F$ is trivial.

Comment: @Mtheorist I thought that $F_{12}$ does not depend on $x$, while $\frac d{dx}$ of $q^{-P\mathrm{sign}(x-y)}=e^{-P\mathrm{sign}(x-y)\ln(q)}$ is $\frac d{dx}(-P\mathrm{sign}(x-y)\ln(q))e^{-P\mathrm{sign}(x-y)\ln(q)}$, is not it so?

Comment: You are right. But $F_21 (-2\textrm{ln}(q)P\delta(x-y))q^{-Psign(x-y)}$ only equals $(-2\textrm{ln}(q)P\delta(x-y))q^{-Psign(x-y)} F_{12}^{-1}$ if we note that $sign(0)=0$.

Comment: Another point I am confused about is your version of my expression at the end of 3., you get a factor of $Pu_1(x+\epsilon)u_2(y+\epsilon)R(x-y)^{-1}$. Should it not be  $u_1(x+\epsilon)u_2(y+\epsilon)PR(x-y)^{-1}$?

Comment: You are right, this $P$ interferes with what I tried to say. In fact there are two things that are not clear to me too. First, what exactly is $R^+(x-y)$: they have $R^+$ and $R(x-y)$ but I could not find their definition for $R^+(x-y)$. Second, what exactly is $\frac d{dx}q^{-P\operatorname{sign}(x-y)}$, is it $-2\ln(q)\delta(x-y)Pq^{-P\operatorname{sign}(x-y)}$ or $-2\ln(q)\delta(x-y)q^{-P\operatorname{sign}(x-y)}P$ or are these two things actually the same? Or is it still something different?

Comment: Oh I think I understand the last part now. $\frac d{dx}q^{-P\operatorname{sign}(x-y)}$ is $-2\ln(q)P$ if $x=y$ and zero otherwise, so it indeed is $-2\ln(q)\delta(x-y)P$, right?

Comment: How I understand it is $\frac{d}{dx}q^{-Psign(x-y)}=-2ln(q)P\delta(x-y)q^{-Psign(x-y)}$, and then we can use the delta function to set $sign(x-y)=sign(0)=0$.